# jQuery, do something while form is posting or in action

Tags: jquery

I got the following form:

```
<form name="x" method="post" action="/message.jsp" onsubmit="validate(this)">

<input type="button" name="Export" value="Export" onclick="this.form.action='ReportExecute.jsp';this.form.submit();">

</form>
```

What I want to do is, I am trying to do something (like displaying an spinner or disabling button) when the export button is cliecked (this button create a csv file to be downloaded eventually after loading some specific data which is specified in the form fields) until the form action (which is exporting data) or form post is finished.

What I did was something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="x"]').submit(function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

I expected to get the alert when I click the export button since the form does some actions by clicking this button, But it never worked! as if the form does not post anything at all!

Would be grateful for some help . thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you mean validate(this) still executes, but you don't get the alert. Or do you mean the form posts and refreshes the screen without doing any javascript?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the `this` keyword in JavaScript. It is a bit of a gotcha for most people moving to JavaScript from traditional object-oriented languages like Java and C# :)

Comment: Abe, I basically need to know how to trigger something when the form starts its action until its done. like the ajax start and stop, but I am not using any ajax call in my case

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to trigger the submit on the wrong HTML element.

The `this.form` in the `onclick` handler of the submit Export button is trying to look for a `form` under the `Export` button, which doesn't exist.

You want to change the 2nd line to the following:

```
<input type="button" name="Export" value="Export" onclick="submitForm();">
```

And add the following JavaScript function in the page:

```
function submitForm() {
    // write whatever you want to do before the form begins to post here
    $('form[name="x"]').attr('action', 'ReportExecute.jsp').submit();
}
```

Write whatever you want to do at the end of the form post in the event handler you provide (where you have currently called the `alert`.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the solution now. I didn't understand the problem in the first go.

Comment: Umar, is that possible to do something when the form starts posting until it finishes its job? something like when ajax starts and stops but in this case I am not using ajax!

Comment: Sure, I have amended the answer to show you where you can do whatever you need to do before the form starts posting. Bear in mind that this is *before* the action property of the form has been updated so if you need the property to be set, just unchain the `attr` and `submit` calls and move the call to `attr` above the `// write`.

Comment: What I mean is for example I click the export button, then an spinner starts displaying until the form action is done (disappear when the action is finished). I did something like the following and it does not work function submitForm() {
 $('#spinIt').addClass("loading");
    $('form[name="messageReport"]').submit();
    $('#spinIt').removeClass("loading");
}

Comment: Just move the call to `removeClass` to where you have `alert("test")` in your code. This is because the `submit` returns immediately and doesn't wait for the form submission to fully complete. When form submission does complete, the callback function you provided is what gets called. Since that is when you want the spinner to disappear, move the `removeClass` in there.

Comment: this is my code function submitForm() {
 $('#spinIt').addClass("loading");
    $('form[name="x"]').submit();
   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form[name="x"]').submit(function() {
  // $('#spinIt').removeClass("loading");
  });
});

Comment: the spinner does not get displayed when I put the removeClass where it is now. when I remove the removeClass line, it appears and it does not go away

Comment: `function() { // $('#spinIt').removeClass("loading"); }` should be `function() { $('#spinIt').removeClass("loading"); }`. You are commenting out the call to `removeClass`, which is why the spinner isn't being removed.

Comment: dude thanks but that comment was only for testing. my code does not have any commented out part and it does not show the spinner. maybe its too quick or something. what i want is, triggering a event while the form is busy and when its done, the event goes away!

Comment: It should be easy to test if it's too quick. Just put an `alert` before the `removeClass` in the callback. If you get the alert, then your code is working fine. It should also show you the spinner in place.

Comment: Hm, there is no problem with `this.form` at all. This property on a form element always points to the parent form.